# ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdw5P.png)in pycharm I'm trying to configure odoo 14, python 3.8,

ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/**init**.py)

receiving the above error in the console. how to overcome this error.

Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMcyl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not certain if this is the exact library you want, but for a recent project I used Image from PIL and used this line to import:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: i am trying to create a virtual environment in pycharm.